# Postfix smtp relayhost with gmail replaces sender address

Tags: postfix-mta

I am configuring postfix and my ISP blocks port 25. To suplement i use gmails smtp server as a relay host. it works fine except that it replaces the sender address with the gmail email. I tried changing the header but it does not change it. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to go into your gmail account and in settings add your mail address. 
then set it to default.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/when-using-gmail-as-an-smtp-server-the-from-address-is-wrong-710837471.html